# Running a file on my computer from an arduino

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

I have an idea for building my own auto-rotating monitor, as in the orientation of the monitor changes when it rotates. Creating the arduino (or raspberry pi or something) to do it would be easy, just getting input from an accelerometer and doing something when it rotates 90 degrees, and creating a python file on my computer to change the orientation of my monitor is fairly easy as well. What I can't figure out is how to get the arduino to call a file on my computer when it receives a signal. Is this even possible, and if so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Arduino won't call a file on your computer directly. It communicates through serial port, and can only send/receive bytes you will have to parse and determine an action.

You will have to make a really basic protocol to send your accelerometer data to your computer (raw data only is enough) through serial port. There, with the serial communication open, you translate it into actions and call the respective script you want.

Making Arduino call a file would require making a library in your Arduino, and an interpreter in your host computer.

As a comment, do not close the serial communication with Arduino until you finish using it, since Arduino resets every time it establishes a new serial connection, generating unwanted delays.

Answer (score 1):

You can't "get the arduino to call a file on [your] computer".

Instead you need to have one program running on each system (ie, both the Arduino and your computer) and have these programs talk to each other over some channel, like the serial port.  A simple example for your case is to have the program on your computer, say, a Python program that uses PySerial, occasionally check the port to see whether a message has been sent from the Arduino about the accelerometer.

There are though, probably easier ways to find the screen orientation.  For example, just getting the screen size, will usually tell you the orientation.  You don't say you platform, but a cross-platform solution would be to use wxPython, and `wx.DisplaySize()`.  There are many other ways as well.

Answer (score 0):

I remember seeing a http library in processing. Maybe you can host a web server on your computer and request the content of the file from the the arduino.

Or if you want to execute a file in the computer, again you can write a tiny webapplication that executes a script when it receives a request from the arduino.